# htmlentities() and user input messing up SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked around for about 15 minutes and couldn't find anything that is having the same issue as what I am.

I have a SIMPLE chat I made on my website, when someone inputs data, it goes though..

```
$m = htmlentities($_POST['m']);
$m = mysql_real_escape_string($m);
```

..then gets inserted into the database like normal. This has worked excellent for keeping people from using HTML code in chat, but today someone found out that inserting ASCII characters (they copy and pasted the "›" symbol) causes JSON to return

```
"chat":null
```

but without that symbol in the returning JSON, it looks like

```
"chat":"<span class=\"chatMessage\"><span style=\"color:#FF7F00\">[12:11:42] Me: Message<\/span><\/span>
```

The row with the symbol in it had

```
&acirc;€&ordm;
```

in it instead of what was supposed to be there.

Comment: Oh, and "or die(mysql_error());" after the query returns nothing.

Comment: What is the charset of the column?

Comment: 4  message  longtext  utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: try a utf8_encode before you send the json

Comment: utf8_encode() worked great to stop the immediate issue! Thank you very much. But now if someone posts "»" it returns "Â»"

Comment: Why you want to allow html tag? They will open security risk?

Comment: No, I don't want to allow HTML tags. I just want to allow ASCII characters to be copy and pasted into chat.

Comment: Just a thought.  I typically always use preg_replace() to eliminate ALL characters except the ones you want.

Comment: Do you have some more filter?

Comment: I have a couple filters, but nothing that would touch the ASCII characters I though. Just simple language filter, remove spaces and check if strlen > 2.

Comment: You do not tell the whole story. We need the code that reads from the database and converts to JSON. The error must be there somewhere. And additionally, the code connecting to the database and writing to it is also interesting. You have plenty of issues, and it is better to get these sorted out.

Comment: Why are you using `htmlentities` when  inserting data into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## reason for "»" displayed as "Â»"

Your data is encoded as utf8, but either a meta tags on your page or the server wrongly tells it's ISO-8859-1 or something else. Fix your headers.